# can't open html in offline mode

Tags: javascript, html

Actually, I face issue that when I upload my files to online server it's work fine and once I try to open it from local (offline) it doesn't work and appear cross origin issue how I can solve this ?

error :

Security Error: Content at file:///Users/othmanali/Desktop/test1/U1/index.html may not load data from file:///Users/othmanali/Desktop/test1/U1/assets/manifest.appcache.
Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object in5.config.js:1101
Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property "book" on cross-origin object in5.config.js:972
Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object in5.config.js:1090
Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object script.js:794

Answer (score 0):

To make it working in local, Chrome extension is avilable.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc

Enable this addon and reload site. Also, Make sure to enable this adddon from top right corner of your browser.

Comment: I did, Thanks for your effort to help.

Answer (score 0):

Lighter than installing an extension, just try changing your local browser settings.

For instance in firefox in the settings change the "privacy.file_unique_origin" parameter.

NB: in recent version (>firefox 95) the parameter has been renammed: "security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy".